# Texture with text in it, looks pixelated, how to fix this in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, textures

Am using a 1024x1024 texture, which am mapping to a quad in Unity3d. The target platform as of now is PC standalone. This is how it looks:

[image: Screenshot]

You can see how pixelated and blurry the objects in the screen are, how can I make it more readable and less pixelated?

Import settings, quality settings and a screenshot of the scene with mip-map turned off [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tsrxm5nyhcz6xja/AACFJJjQBkCtWSFDEbN9FwjQa?dl=0).  The texture and the quad asset can be [found here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tsrxm5nyhcz6xja/AACFJJjQBkCtWSFDEbN9FwjQa?dl=0).

Comment: can you share your quality setting?

Comment: If you look at the triangle at low angle, like a floor or your cards it tends to loose texture resolution quite fast. Try to use "anisotropic" as your filtering mode and see if it helps - it was invented for such situations.

Comment: Yes you are right, so what am going to do is try to use higher res texture and play with the camera angle. Hopefully I should get better results.

Comment: You may also look at the table from top to separate texture-related issues from view-related ones, this may help. Let us know how it ended.

Comment: *"with mip-map turned off"*!  If you have MIP mapping disabled you end up with with worse results due to aliasing artefacts _and_, to rub salt into the wound, [degraded performance](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/357/is-using-many-texture-maps-bad-for-caching/419#419).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image looks fine to me: it looks like a 3D video game.

Note that **1k is very small** to use as a PNG for the texture for an object which will **appear that large** in your final scene.

Secondly click on the texture, and then `Inspector`.

Note particularly the "Max Size" setting, which indeed should be bigger than the literal size of your PNG. Learn about the "Mip Maps" concept as anim_it says. Also note your "Filter Mode".  And indeed the "Texture Type". These settings all need to be "just right" for a given game situation.

Particularly read the two comments by Kolanda above which well-explain **anisotropic** handling: *If you see an object **at low angle**, like a floor or your cards, it tends to lose texture resolution fast. Try to use **"anisotropic"** as your filtering mode and see if it helps - it was invented for such situations. As a test **move the camera, to view the table from above,** to separate texture-related issues from view-related issues.*

[image]

You should probably include a screenshot of your Inspector for the texture, to get more detailed help. BTW the quad you are using is totally unrelated.

Comment: I have pretty much tried everything that has to do with the import settings. I don't know if am missing something silly. I included the quad, cause I was thinking maybe it could be some uv related issue perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the tic "Generate Mip Maps"