# Textures look blurry up close but good from a distance Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

This issue seems to be the reverse of what  others have when researching this. My material looks great from some distance but blurry up close at all angles. My image is 1024 x 1024 px. How do I fix this? I display my import settings in the screenshots. Even though max size is 2048 I also tried 1024 with the same result.

[image: good quality]

[image: blurry image]

[image: close 2]

Comment: I completely answered this question - which is asked over and over - here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34876849/294884  (Lots of other people have fully answered it also.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Texure with text in it, looks pixelated, how to fix this in unity3d?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875262/texure-with-text-in-it-looks-pixelated-how-to-fix-this-in-unity3d)

Comment: None of those options in your answer fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using "Filter Mode : Point" gives sharp pixels,
or adjusting Aniso Level "Increases texture quality when viewing the texture at a steep angle"

More info about each of those settings:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html

Or if you add tiling to the material (default is 1, try 10), it looks better when viewed near, but can cause issues if its not seamless texture..

Comment: I tried those options with no change. I added a straight on view of the texture. The angle doesn't seem to effect the image quality