# I have a Unity image format issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

this is my image

photoshop image is good to smooth

but import to unity a little Crash

what's problem?

Comment: please include the import settings in the inspector. Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34875262/1092820) help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like anti aliasing is missing in the Sprite Slicing Editor. Don't worry about that.
In general: Click the Image in the Unity Explorer and look into the Inspector - it will show you the Import Settings. There, you can choose the Format to be "Sprite" and also compression and the mip-map generation (downsampling)